# Required help in a query

Tags: database, postgresql

I wanted to take count of records based on some condition.

Here's what the condition is.

data:

```
"col1"  "col2"  "col3
A   Y   Y
A   Y   Y
A   N   Y
A   N   Y
A   N   Y
A       Y
A       Y
A   N   Y
B   Y   N
B   Y   Y
B   N   Y
B   N   N
B   Y   Y
B   N   Y
C   Y   N
C   Y   Y
C   N   Y
C   Y   Y
C   N   Y
C   Y   Y
```

I need to take the count of `Y` from `col3` excluding the `N` of `col2` where the `col1` value is `A`. My head is cracking when i think of doing it.

Note : `N` values of col2 must be excluded only where the col1 value is A. The null values also need to be included along with `Y` passing the criteria where the col3 value is `Y`.

Please help me.

I need to get the count as `11` if the query is correct.

Code i tried with.

```
Select
    'Yes' as "label",
    Count(*)    
FROM Table1
Where "date" between '2014-03-01' And '2014-03-05'
And
"col3" = 'Y' and ("col1"  'C' and "col2"  'N')
```

I have the idea to how to do it orally. By i couldn't figure out a way to do it in `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: something like `col3 = y and not (col1 = a and col2= n)?`

Comment: Nope. `count(col3 = 'Y' or null)` is taking the entire count instead of the criteria mentioned there.

Comment: Did you try my query example? `SELECT ... WHERE date ... AND col3 = 'Y' AND NOT (col1='a' AND col2='N')`

Comment: Yes!!! Amazing! It gave me a correct result but i made a mistake in the question. There are some null values in `col2` and i wanted to include those null values too.

Comment: I've edited the question. I need to include the null values too. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
Select
    'Yes' as "label",
    Count(*)    
FROM Table1
Where "date" between '2014-03-01' And '2014-03-05'
AND col3 = 'Y' AND NOT (col1='A' AND col2 IS NOT NULL AND col2='N')
```

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question. I need to include the count of null values in `col2` where `col3` value is `Y`. Please help.

Comment: As a separate or just include in general result?

Comment: Not separate, along the with result generated.

Comment: So you need query where col3 is Y, excluded where col1=a and col2=n?

Comment: No!! Now with the query you given me i got the exact result. But there were no null values in col2. Now i've added two null values in col2 but the col3 value is `Y`. So now I need to get +2 in the result with the query you've given me. More likely I only need to exclude the 'N` values not the null values too. Null values needs to counted if the col3 value is `Y`.

Comment: Look, I am looking for a way to help you, you just need to explain better. You need count of where col3='Y', that's ok? What do you need to exclude from the count?

Comment: I only need to exclude 'N' values. If we have null values in col2 with the value of Y in col3. We need to consider it. Hope so you are clear now.

Comment: Well that is what my first query does? It excludes only the col2='N' values where col1='a'? Or do you want to exclude all col2='N' values? See my edit, it counts all the values where col3 is y, and excludes those where col1='a' and col2='n'. It should take into count null values.

Comment: It is of course excluding the 'N' values. But it also excluding the null values in the `col2`. I wanted to consider the count of null values too when the `col3` is `Y` for the corresponding row. And i'm using the edited from the beginning.

Comment: Looks like this should do the same thing as my answer, but with more condensed logic and without `OR` (so it will likely be faster on large tables).

Comment: Can you try this query? If it gives you the same result, you should use this one, because it is more efficient than COALESCE()

Comment: Yes. Its giving me the same result and the execution times is also the same. What's more efficient in this query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    count(col3 = 'Y' or null) - count(col2 = 'N' and col1 = 'A' or null) as "Yes"
from table1
where
    "date" between '2014-03-01' and '2014-03-05'
```

Comment: `col3 = 'Y'` this is not getting applied from this `count(col3 = 'Y' or null)`. I get the entire records including `N` too.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the `A` and `not A` as two different cases try something like this:

```
Select 'Yes' as "label", Count(*)    
FROM Table1
Where "date" between '2014-03-01' And '2014-03-05'
and   "col3" = 'Y'
And   (("col1" = 'A' And "col2" <> 'N') Or ("col1" <> 'A'))
```